# Jenkins exception

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use `SSH` Tectia for our SSH connectivity. In my Jenkins job, i have provided the userid (destination) and the `private keyfile` (absolute path in the Source box). When i try to test the configuration it fails with the below exception

```
Failed to connect or change directory

jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect session for config [SomeName]. Message [Auth fail]
```

But the same connection id works through `command prompt` and i can see the keyfile is the same that i have provided.

Answer (score 2):

You did not tell what kind of SSH operation you are doing in Jenkins. However, most uses of SSH in Jenkins do not require calling the external SSH client (the "ssh" command). Jenkins has a built-in java implementation of the SSH protocol that it uses for most things involving SSH.

The private key file for the Jenkins SSH client functionality needs to be in the OpenSSH format. If my memory serves, the Tectia SSH uses a different key format. You should be able to convert the key for Jenkins using the `ssh-keygen` tool. See the man page of the tool.